# Cascade delete Entity Framework Identity User with relations

Tags: razor, .net-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc

I have using .net Core 3.1 scaffolded Identity and extended that with my own classes. But when I use the build in DeletePersonalData.OnPostAsync() it fails due to my relations from my other classes. I don't get how I make the delete to delete all the extended classes too.

**Error message:**

> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
>   constraint "FK_Workspaces_AspNetUsers_OwnerId". The conflict occurred
>   in database "myupload", table "dbo.Workspaces", column 'OwnerId'. The
>   statement has been terminated.
>   Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.b__164_0(Task
>   result)

**Extended Identity:**

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<MyFile> MyFiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Workspace> Workspaces { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WorkspacePermission> WorkspacePermissions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.Entity<Workspace>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Owner)
                .WithMany()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<MyFile>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Workspace)
                .WithMany(b => b.MyFile);
        }
    }
```

**And the delete method:**

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        RequirePassword = await _userManager.HasPasswordAsync(user);
        if (RequirePassword)
        {
            if (!await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Input.Password))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Incorrect password.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        var result = await _userManager.DeleteAsync(user);
        var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Unexpected error occurred deleting user with ID '{userId}'.");
        }

        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        _logger.LogInformation("User with ID '{UserId}' deleted themselves.", userId);

        return Redirect("~/");
    }
}
```

**One of the Classes:**

```
public class Workspace
{
    // Base
    public Guid WorkspaceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Security
    public virtual IdentityUser Owner { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    // Files
    public virtual ICollection<MyFile> MyFile { get; set; }


    // Statistics

    public Workspace()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: @GertArnold Well how do i define them with cascade delete? Im using Entity Framework with Code first.

Comment: @GertArnold I had no success with that. I added what i thought would do it without success. Same error message

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your pointer. I finally solved it. If you want me to accept your answer please add one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fluent API I managed to add the Cascade Delete to the IdentityUser with this Code in the OnModelCreating method.

```
         builder.Entity<Workspace>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Owner)
                .WithMany()
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

            builder.Entity<MyFile>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Workspace)
                .WithMany(b => b.MyFile);
```